# Google Tag Manager Container Setup for iOS in PROD and STAGING

Tags: ios, xcode, google-tag-manager

I am trying to put 2 containers in my XCode project (1 for STAGING and another for PROD). Is this possible in Google Tag Manager? If so, how do I achieve it?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en

Comment: Hmmm, I'm actually not sure. From my understanding this is done for web apps.
What I want to achieve is to add two (2) GTM-XXXXXXXX.json file in one project that I can use to instantiate my GTM on app launch depending on environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use build script to copy necessary file to *yourProjectName/container* folder before run.

Go to *Project -> Targets -> YourTarget -> Build Phases*, add *New Run Script Phase*, add script like this:

```
rm -vf ${SRCROOT}/container/*
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
cp -v "${SRCROOT}/App/Analytics/GoogleTagManager/XXXXXXX_release.json" "${SRCROOT}/container/GTM-XXXXXXX.json"
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then
cp -v "${SRCROOT}/App/Analytics/GoogleTagManager/YYYYYYY_debug.json" "${SRCROOT}/container/GTM-YYYYYYY.json"
fi
```

Folder *yourProjectName/container* will be cleared every run, and debug or release container .json file will be copied.